# NHibernate: Map a collection onto an entity when the actual data link is via another table

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Using NHibernate 3.3 with XML mapping files.

I have the following database structure, but would like my NHibernate entities to reflect the ReportComponentOverrides as a collection on ReportComponent.  I would then lookup the overrides I was interested in based on the ReportDefinition I was working with.

Because of the intermediate (ReportDefinitionComponent) table, I can't see a way to map the Overrides to the Components.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

```
                            ReportDefinition
                                   |
                                   |
                                   *
                        ReportDefinitionComponent *--- ReportComponentOverride
                                   *
                                   |
                                   |
 ReportComponentType *----  ReportComponent
```

My current effort:

```
<class name="ReportComponent" table="ReportComponent">
  <id name="ID" type="Int32">
    <column name="ID" />
    <generator class="identity" />
  </id>
  <map name="Overrides" table="ReportDefinitionComponent">
    <key column="ReportComponentID"/>
    <many-to-many column="ReportDefinitionComponentID" class="ReportComponentOverride" />
  </map>
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would expect something like

```
<map name="Overrides" table="ReportDefinitionComponent">
  <key column="ReportComponentID"/>
  <index-many-to-many column="ReportDefinition_Id" class="ReportDefinition"/>
  <many-to-many column="ReportComponentOverrideID" class="ReportComponentOverride" />
</map>
```